# extend unknown super class with decorator pattern and override functions

Tags: java, android

I want to extend the `Fragment` class, but I want to be able to use my class with HoloEverywhere and with the default Fragments...

So I tried using a decorator...

```
public abstract class RFragment<F extends Fragment, I extends LayoutInflater> extends Fragment implements IKey
{
    private final Class<F> mFragmentClass;
    private final Class<I> mInflatorClass;

    public RFragment(Class<F> fragmentClass, Class<I> inflatorClass)
    {
        this.mFragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        this.mInflatorClass = inflatorClass;
    }
}
```

I now as well want to override the `onCreateView`, but I can't do it. What I try is following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(I inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = doOnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        loadingIndicator = doGetLoadingIndicatorView(view);
    }
    return view;
}
protected abstract View doOnCreateView(I inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState);
protected abstract View doGetLoadingIndicatorView(View view);
```

but that is not allowed, because I can't override the function, if the parameter don't match (I != LayoutInflator)

Is it somehow possible to solve this problem? I want to avoid to copy my class and just change the imports from the default fragment and default LayoutInflator to the ones from HoloEveryhwere (which only extends the default classes)...

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the function this way because `I` is more precise that `LayoutInflater`
I suggest you use something tike that :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    I infl = (I) inflater; // May be unchecked
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = doOnCreateView(infl, container, savedInstanceState);
        loadingIndicator = doGetLoadingIndicatorView(view);
    }
    return view;
}
```

---

In fact, I wonder why you need to use a TypeVariable for I. You got a subclass of LayoutInflater ? Maybe just using LayoutInflater everywhere should be enough ?

Comment: HoloEverywhere is a library (not from me) which can be used to get the visual style of Holo on older android systems as well... they extend the layout inflator as well... so the `onCreateView` will be called with the `org.holoeverywhere.LayoutInflator` in the first case and with the `android.view.LayoutInflater` in the second case...

Comment: Didn't knew =) Thanks. Did you try the first part of my answer ?

Comment: actually, that won't work... the holo library makes the `onCreateView` final and internally deside which LayoutInflator to use (own or default) because on a new android system the default one is used and only on old ones the own one is used...